# Unity Client-Server separate different and State Synchronization?

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, client-server, multiplayer

As what title said, i still confusing and turn around in deep-hole and get lost about one month in it. So i really need help.

I would like to create client-server online game, and separate Client and Server to different project with each other, and for understanding, i **don't using any NetworkManager and script from demo project**.

Why i do that ? I want client is always remote client, and server always dedicated server that mean no local client.

- All communication until now i using custom message from MessageBase and it ok for me. But the problem come with spawn game object, sync with all remote client, i don't know how to do that.
- The server just handle connection, message and send back to client so it just GUI only, then i want to ask that it MUST be share scenes at client ? Does it NEED TO DO IT ?
- The client is a remote client, so how to sync movement, spawn, and etc to another client via server ? If i using transfer message base on MessageBase, it look so complicate than using SyncVar or Command. But i don't know how Server handle Command, because it separate different with Client. Can anyone help ?
- AM I WRONG WAY ?

Comment: Why do you want to seperate the server and client projects? Have you ever thought about having only one project, with shared server/client code?

Comment: Sorry for not reply to it. Sure I was using UNET from that on and Mirror right now. And this question I already find the answer for myself. Thanks a lot